# Распознавание речи для чайников

Tags: распознавание-речи

Я начал изучать распознавание речи. Я читал статьи много стало непонятно(Как обрабатывать MFCC к примеру и т.д. ). Посоветуйте, какой-нибудь хороший учебник, где все подробно описано. Ответ типа есть готовые инструменты не пойдет. Я хочу понимать весь процесс, который происходит.

Answer (score 2):

1.Huang, Acero, Hon,  Spoken Language Processing (https://www.twirpx.com/file/663451/)
2. Introduction to Automatic Speech Recognition, MIT (https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-345-automatic-speech-recognition-spring-2003/lecture-notes/lecture1.pdf) и так далее 23 лекции: (https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-345-automatic-speech-recognition-spring-2003/lecture-notes/lecture2.pdf)
3. Automatic_Speech_Recognition_A_Deep_Learning_Approach. (http://b-ok.org/book/2594076/2e564a)
где-то в пункте 3 можно начинать забывать про MFCC

Возможны другие многообразные варианты.